# SwaggerUI: show/hide a hidden schema field

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi

I am trying to set-up an OpenApi documentation within a project. Currently, I am documenting an endpoint which receives a DTO and returns a DTO as a response.

My entity DTO has a private field hidden (via @Schema annotation: the id). I used this anno. for not having that field included in the example JSON for a POST..

All good so far, but I want to have the id displayed in the response example value JSON within swagger-ui.

The example is same for response and request:
{
"title": "string",
"subtitle": "string",
"publisher": "string",
"publishedDate": "string",
"description": "string",
"pageCount": 0,
"language": "string",
"previewLink": "string",
"numberOfItems": 0
}

But for the sake of documentation of the "response", I want the below JSON to contain also the hidden schema field. Can I do this somehow?
[Image example]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsXfJ.jpg)

My approach towards was the following:

@ApiResponse(description = "Successful response", responseCode = "200",content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = BookDto.class)))

But I am expecting to be able without making a custom @Content schema, to include in the API response documentation example the hidden field.

Comment: Please explain further, I don't really get what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank your interest in helping, Alex.
My problem is the following: Swagger-ui is providing an example of a JSON for one of the GET endpoints. The example does not include the field "id" of my DTO because it was previously annotated with @Schema(hidden=true). 

It was annotated to be hidden because I don't want that field to be included in the JSON example provided by Swagger for the POST endpoint. But meanwhile, I want that field to be included in the JSON example provided for the GET endpoint.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution for my encounter.

Instead of using `@Schema(hidden=true)` for the `id` field within my DTO. I switched to using: `@Schema(accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)`.

Which changed the behavior of Swagger as I wanted.